# How to fix Streaming API errors when using Apex Debugger?

Tags: apex, eclipse, apex-debugger

I am attempting to use the Apex Interactive Debugger using Eclipse. When I try to run it I continously get messages from Eclipse 'You have been temporarily disconnected from the Streaming API. We will attempt to reconnect in the background' The debugger itself actually seems to work although the messages make it unusable, turning off notifications in Eclipse does not seem to work.